# How do I implement Session Timeout feature in MOSS2007/WSS ?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I want to implement the session timeout feature in my SharePoint application. I tried to set this up in the following way:

```
Central Administration --> Application Management--> Configure Session State.
```

I have set a time frame here but it is not working. Can anyone suggest any other way I can have the same feature?

Thanks in advance,

Satheesh

Answer (score 0):

It is just a .NET web app. You could always set it in the web.config. Or if you are feeling crazy, there is always the machine.config.